# How to use Map/Set to improve the code to O(n)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Maybe I should use Map/Set, but I can not work it out...

```js
let items = [
  {type: 'a', name: 'a1', color: 'yellow'},
  {type: 'b', name: 'b1', color: 'orange'}
];
const excludes = [
  {k: 'color', value: 'yellow'},
  {k: 'name', value: 'x'}
];

excludes.forEach((exclude) => {
  items = items.filter((item) => item[exclude.k] !== exclude.value)
})

console.log(items)
```

Comment: Please define in your question what *n* is to designate. And check the spelling in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O(n) means linear complexity. Here is an example code that does it in a linear complexity and checks all the keys of items.

You can use a `Set` to index excludes for each key to reduce filtering complexity to O(1). Below is an example code for O(n) + O(m) =~ O(n)

```js
const items = [
  { type: "a", name: "a1", color: "yellow" },
  { type: "b", name: "b1", color: "orange" },
];
const excludes = [
  { k: "color", value: "yellow" },
  { k: "name", value: "x" },
];


const excludeIndex = { type: new Set(), name: new Set(), color: new Set() };

// Populate Exclude Index: O(m)
excludes.forEach((exclude) => excludeIndex[exclude.k].add(exclude.value));

// Filter Items: O(n)
const result = items.filter(
  (item) => !excludeIndex.type.has(item.type) && !excludeIndex.name.has(item.name) && !excludeIndex.color.has(item.color),
);

console.log(result);
```

Normally, we should use a variable for storing index keys and iterate them to make the code more flexible. However, iterating index keys may confuse reviewers about the complexity. The number of keys is constant (or negligible) and does not affect complexity.

Comment: excellent!  properties is limited in the real-world

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid to read the input at least. That already costs O(n). So you need to check if an element needs to be excluded in O(1).

The data structure that comes in mind that could do that (at least in most cases) is a Hash-Map/-Set.

---

**P.s.**
I'm not 100% sure what *Alexandre Fenyo* wants to point out in his comments, but I agree that a Hash-Map/-Set cannot guarantee O(1) for lookup and insert because of possible collisions.
To minimize collisions the Hash-Map/-Set needs to be of adequate size (or have a relative cheap way to grow its internal structure) and the hash-function used must not create too many collisions because of its design.
For further details [wikipedia hash-table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) .
For good implementations you get O(1) in most cases, that is what I mean with "in most cases" in my answer above.

Comment: If n is the number of items and m the number of excluded items, the check is O(m)

Comment: @Alexandre Fenyo: For each of the n items the check with a hashset takes O(1) (on average) which leads to O(n)*O(1)=O(n).

Comment: my AI answer also like that. hha

Comment: @MrSmith42 : I disagree, a hash function may encounter collisions. We are on a computer, therefore both the start and end sets are finite. Some collisions will occur in the case the end set is smaller than the start set. Even without collisions, we do not know which hash function would be used. Since the end set is finite, you can not prove that it is better than O(m). Because there exists hash functions that are O(m): any constant function (it has m collisions). What do you mean with "on average"? If you do not agree with me, may you please tell me which principle the proof is based on?

Comment: To get the fastest implementation, you need to sort "items" and "excludes" arrays. If n is the size of the "items" array and m is the size of the "excludes "array, the best algorithm implemented on a computer (i.e. with finished size memory) will be O(n.ln(n)) + O(m.ln(m)).

Comment: @Alexandre Fenyo: The `excludes` are a constant (you say of size m (But o(n+m) with m constant is O(n)). With 'on average' I meant that if we use a hash-function there might be collisions which needs handling that might exceed O(1) in this cases [Since `excludes` are constant we can search for a hash-function without collisions which would guarantee O(1) ].

Comment: @MrSmith412 In the program, excludes is a constant  because is it not updated when the program runs, like in the fact(n) program (when well programmed, recursively). Therefore, would you then say fact(n) is O(1) ??? Moreover, excludes can be constant, but if you accept to feat the function that gives the result as you like, you always have a fonction that is O(1) to compute any algorithm: take the input, compute the output, say your function is a hash function that gives the output for each input without any collision.  This is wrong since hash fcts complexity depends on the size of the input.

Comment: @Alexandre Fenyo; If 'excludes' is not constant but part of the  input I agree that the usage of a hashSet would be O(n+m) (on average (because of possible collisions)). But this is still linear in size of the input, like requested in the question,

Comment: @MrSmith42 What do you mean with « on average »? Is it an average computed on the set of hash functions, on the set of input values, on the set of output values, etc.?

Comment: @Alexandre Fenyo; "O(1) performance of the lookup" see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table . Depending on how you handle collisions these might be a bit more expensive,

Comment: The only constant you can assume in the example is the number of "attributes" of items ("type", "name", "color"). As @Alexandre Fenyo stated, other variables cannot be assumed constant because the soul of the question is based on variable length excludes used to filter variable length items.

I added an answer for linear complexity. Could you please review it and share your thoughts?

Comment: @özüm: If 'exludes' is constant or part of the input has no effect on my answer. Creating the hashSet takes O(#excludes=:m) and  checking the 'items' takes O(#items=:n) makes O(n+m)  which is linear in size of the input as requested.

Comment: @MrSmith42 The O(1), in the Wikipedia page, is when using "a well-dimensioned hash table", as written in the content of the page. Again, may you explain how you would prove that searching with an unknown hash function could, on average on the input set (since this is the type of average chosen in the Wikipedia page), be O(n), with n being the "items" table size? I mean you can prove it is O(n), but you can not prove it is O(1). Thanks.